# Node.js SQL server crashes when receiving multiple requests

Tags: sql-server, node.js, typescript, nodemon

I have a NodeJS application which is my server and I created a Database class to help me handle querying my SQL DB. If I send requests a second between each other, everything runs fine.. no problems.. But if I start spamming requests to my server it crashes due to `Error: Cannot enqueue Quit after invoking quit.`

Here's my query function inside my Database class

```
static query(query: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log('Query: ' + query);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.connect().then(success => {
            sqlConn.query(query, (err, results) => {
                if (err) { return reject(err);
                } else {
                    return resolve(results);
                }
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            return reject(err);
        }).then( () => {
           if (sqlConn.state !== 'disconnected') {
            sqlConn.end();
           }
        });
    });
};
```

and here's the `this.connect()` function

```
static connect(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sqlConn = mysql.createConnection(this.connectionData);
        sqlConn.connect(err => {
            if (err) { return reject(err); } else {
                return resolve('SQL connection established');
            }
        });
    });
};
```

> I'm pretty sure the problem appears sometimes, it would still be
>   processing one query, and then another query comes before the first
>   one finishes, so it would call `sqlConn.end()` twice, even when it's
>   already disconnected? Any help is greatly appreciated...
>
> **> Main goal is for the query to wait till it's 100% done before it runs
>   the next one..**

Comment: why you not define a pool size for mysql connection and i think this might resolve your problem... and use the same connection for second query and setup some idle time to end your connection

Comment: Look at this part of the mysql npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections

What you should do is do acquire a connection from the pool, execute the query, then release the connection back to the query.  The acquire function will automatically wait for a free connection before resolving the promise (or rejects with a timeout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using the npm module `mysql` and use it's built-in connection pool.

From [the documentation](http://npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections):

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});

pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

You can, of course, create your own function that promisifies that call like this:

```
function query (sql) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => 
      error ? reject(error) : resolve({ results, fields });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really wants to use this approach then please use **eachSeries** function of **async** library.

```
var chunkedArray= [];
async.eachSeries(chunkedArray, startUpload, endUpload);

funtion startUpload(data,cb){
    //iterate over every single item in array 1 at a time
    }

function endUplaod(err){

//finally call this
}
```

This might help:-
https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries

But i rather suggest you to use pooling of connection which make less overhead on your db and you can use your mysql more efficiently then making multiple connection.

```
// Load module
var mysql = require('mysql');
// Initialize pool
var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'db_name',
    debug    :  false
});    
module.exports = pool;
```